# How to change app background except textview's background?

Tags: android, xml

I want change background for whole app except textviews. 
So, I change style.xml

```
<item name="android:background">@color/colorRed</item>
```

But textviews change background too. For example, toast text appear on red background.  As I understand, default textview background is transparent. Is there posibilitiy to change background without textviews?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a background (android:background) to the text view on the xml file, like this

```
<TextView
    android:background="android.R.color.white"
```

That background will not change because it's fixed.